# How to remove error sound from Pycharm terminal?

Tags: sound, gnome-terminal, settings, system-settings, pycharm

I am using Ubuntu 17.10 which has a really irritating error sound. I have disabled it from terminal's Profile Preference section. But the error sound is still coming from **Pycharm's** terminal.

How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Inside PyCharm: Go to ***File*→*Settings*→*Tools*→*Terminal***  and disable **Audible bell**.

[image]

Comment: I tried searching for 'sound', 'noise', 'volume' and 'notification' in settings - it would have been a while before I tried 'bell'!

Comment: thank, you saved me frustration.

Comment: Does not work for me for some reason on MacOS Big Sur version 11.6